# How to style SWT Section Title with Twistie?

Tags: java, css, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm trying to style a `Section` title of an Eclipse RCP application through CSS.

```
toolkit.createSection(body, Section.TITLE_BAR);
```

Creating a `Section` without `Section.TWISTIE` I can simply style the `Section` color:

```
Section { color: #00ff00; }
```

As soon as I add the `Section.TWISTIE`, the color is not used anymore:

```
toolkit.createSection(body, Section.TWISTIE | Section.TITLE_BAR);
```

So I started some debugging and found this in `FormColors`:

```
private void createTwistieColors() {
    RGB rgb = getColor(IFormColors.TITLE).getRGB();
    RGB white = getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
    createColor(TB_TOGGLE, rgb);
    rgb = blend(rgb, white, 60);
    createColor(TB_TOGGLE_HOVER, rgb);
}
```

The `IFormColors.TITLE` is created in `createTitleColor()`:

```
RGB listSelection = getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION);
```

No CSS is used, how can I change the color of the Section header?

**Example UI:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, still hoping for a CSS only solutions though:

```
FormColors colors = new FormColors(parent.getDisplay()) {
    @Override
    public void initializeSectionToolBarColors() {
        super.initializeSectionToolBarColors();
        // override createTwistieColors() declaration with own color
        RGB rgb = new RGB(80, 80, 80);
        RGB white = getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
        createColor(IFormColors.TB_TOGGLE, rgb);
        rgb = blend(rgb, white, 60);
        createColor(IFormColors.TB_TOGGLE_HOVER, rgb);
    }
};
toolkit = new FormToolkit(colors);
```

Comment: The Eclipse CSS code just calls various methods in the normal classes. If there is no method to set the colour then the CSS can't do it.